# How to generate multiple layout and get value of each filed in it in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Actually i am going on with the page which has a add button if the user click add button it
should generate multiple layoutwith DropDown and edittext tried it programatically how can i take each value of dropDown 
and edittext from all layout and pass it.

(for eg: if user click the button for 10 times it should generate 10 layout with the fields but the their is no limit for click).

If any other approach please help me out to solve this issue.

Tried:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progm_view);

EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setId(i);
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(editText);

int i = edittext.getId();
editText.setTag("data");
EditText ed = (EditText)findViewByTag("data");
String text = ed.getText().toString();
```

Comment: post the code which is already done

Answer (score 0):

Have an xml with dropdown and edittexts.  Whenever user clicks, inflate the layout and add to the parent layout, so that you can user `getChildAt(position)` method to get each inflated layout so as to get the dropdown and edittext objects.

Comment: i had tried it already actually i'm setting the value for dropdown from webserivce the value only sets for first layout for the rest it dosen't

Comment: usually we will set the value for the fields like android:id="@+id/spinner" the value of spinner sets only for the first layout for rest it's empty do u have any idea how about it.